# PHP while loop to display images from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, image, while-loop

I have a MySQL table storing images and a code which displays an image on the site.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM upload";
$sth = $db->query($sql);
$result=mysqli_fetch_array($sth);

echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $result['content'] ).'"/>';
```

I want to display all images with a while loop.

Please don't tell me "Don't put images in your database" or something like that.

Answer (score 2):

Your approach is wrong from the beginning! Saving as a blob type is not a good approach anymore as it just puts additional load on the database. Instead, what you should do is upload file to a specific folder on your hosting using:

```
move_uploaded_file($filetmp,$filepath);
```

- [Guide for move_uploaded_file](http://www.tutorialscollection.com/php-move_uploaded_file-how-to-use-move_uploaded_file-to-move-uploaded-file-to-specified-location/)

Then save the uploaded file path in the database.

After that, wherever you need to use the images get the path from db and in src of img echo that path.